# Does the average value of hands drawn from a deck change whether you shuffle the hand back regularly or not?

Tags: probability

Were I to shuffle a standard 52-card deck, then draw 5 cards from the top of the deck, note down what hand I got (for example as in poker), then set those cards aside and draw 5 new ones from the leftover deck until the deck had 2 cards left. I would then shuffle the deck and repeat the process a lot of times.

Would this yield a different result than if I were to draw 5 cards from the top of the deck, note down what hand I got, then shuffle the deck immediately and repeat the process a lot of times.

---

Intuitively, if I were to look at the first five cards, the average hand I'd draw from the remaining cards would either increase or decrease in value. Therefore the average would change if I were to shuffle the five cards back in.

On the other hand, if I were to take five cards, not look at them, then take the next five cards, the first draw wouldn't influence my second draw.

Comment: Your second intuition is correct.  "first draw" hasn't got a mathematical meaning. Maybe the way I get my "first draw" is to take out ten and take the last five.  The distribution is identical.

Comment: The flaw in the first distribution is that it is incomplete.  Yes, the first draw could be stronger or weaker than average.  If you knew which it was, you'd have gained information about the second draw.  As it is, you know nothing of the value so the two scenarios cancel.

Comment: As a numerical illustration, let us compute the probability that, say the $A\spadesuit$ is in either the first or second draw.   The probability that it is in the first is $\frac 5{52}$.  If it is in the first, then it can't be in the second.  If it isn't in the first then it has a probability $\frac 5{47}$ of being in the second.  Thus the probability that it is in fact in the second is $\frac 5{52}\times 0 +\frac {47}{52}\times \frac 5{47}=\frac 5{52}$ as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing lots of times (without replacement) gives the same average probability per hand. Thus the average of the hands would be the same. However, the chance of a *particular* scenario could change:

Consider the following example. Suppose I had 4 cards, 2 black and two white, and I drew cards in pairs. Then obviously I can either get black/white or black-black or white-white. Now, there are two types of hands in my new game: *single* - one of each colour and *double* - two of the same colour. With replacement, the average per hand is independent and is 50% of each per game. Without replacement, however, means that in the first two hands *it is impossible to have one of each hand*. However, there is a 50% chance of 2 doubles and a 50% chance of two singles. Thus the average chance remains the same.

Elaborating on the first paragraph, the three scenarios (for two draws) are: two singles, a single and a double and two doubles. With replacement means that a single and a double has 50% chance of happening whereas without replacement gives a 0% chance of this happening.

So, in conclusion, the 'average draw' of any particular hand would not change, but the collective chance of all hands being special in some way (e.g in the poker example, all 4-of-a-kind: with replacement, it is *just* possible, without replacement guarantees a fail) changes.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  The question, as I understand it, is "is the distribution of the second draw the same as the distribution of the first ?".   Of course, if you look at either of the draws that information will change the distribution.  Say there are only two cards, white and black, and that you draw one a time.  It's clear (is it not?) that the distribution of the two draws is identical.  However if you look at either one then you know the results of both.

Comment: Actually, that two card example encapsulates what I'm saying. Although the probability for any single draw is the same, the overall outcome without replacement (1 white and 1 black/two draws) changes.

Comment: I don't understand.  It only changes if you acquire new information, but that is always the case.  Yes, if you look at one draw you acquire information about the other.  But that is not what the OP is asking.

Comment: *Would this yield a different result than if I were to draw 5 cards from the top of the deck, note down what hand I got, then shuffle the deck immediately and repeat the process a lot of times.* Applying this to the 2 card deck, *yes* the result would be different - specifically, without replacement, we have drawn *exactly* the same amount of each card (thus the probability distribution has just one nonzero point), whereas with replacement the probability distribution is normal.

Comment: Sorry, that text you quote clearly refers to the "with replacement scenario".  That's what "shuffle the deck" means. It is absolutely clear that in the non-replacement scenario you get information about hands by looking at others.  If the $A\spadesuit$ is in one hand it can't be in another.  Anyway, let's let the OP comment.

Comment: Well, were I sure about this, I wouldn't be asking the question in the first place, but Wen seems to be correct. Clearly the second draw is not identical in average "value" to the first once we already know the first draw, but I was indeed interested in the average over a longer series of draws. It seems that knowing the first draw can influence the average equally either way, and on average doesn't change it. Reducing the amount of cards helps draw an easier parallel, which seems more believable to me, at least.